# vsftpd Unable to log in to ftp using Berkeley DB (V4) databases and PAM (pam_userdb.so)

Tags: centos, ftp, pam, vsftpd

I just recently tried setting up `vsftpd`, following [this nixCraft article on cyberciti](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-fedora-centos-vsftpd-installation.html) and [their article to set up virutal users](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/centos-redhat-vsftpd-ftp-with-virtual-users.html).

I can connect using `ftp localhost` but it doesn't recognize the username `vivek` as pointed out by the log:

```
vsftpd: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): check pass; user unknown 
vsftpd: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=vivek
vsftpd: pam_succeed_if(vsftpd:auth): error retrieving information about user vivek
```

everything should have been done the exact same as the tutorials, with the exception that I used `/var/www/$USER` rather than what they had specified.

It's almost like it can't find the db for pam_userdb.so or it can't read it properly to be able to find the password.

Here's my `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER
hide_ids=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
banner_file=/etc/vsftpd/issue
```

Here's my `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
session    optional    pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
auth       required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/f$
auth       required    pam_shells.so
auth       include     system-auth
account    include     system-auth
session    include     system-auth
session    required    pam_loginuid.so
auth       required    pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
account    required    pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
session    required    pam_loginuid.so
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Is there any way I can find out more info to see if it's finding/using the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` file, it turns out I was only supposed to have the last three lines (the ones they provided in the tutorial).

After I changed the file to this:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required    pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
account    required    pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
session    required    pam_loginuid.so
```

It worked just fine. However, I haven't used it long enough to figure out whether it created errors elsewhere. Please let me know if anyone sees anything wrong with this change.